# Remove rows in a pandas dataframe between two specific values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove rows in a pandas dataframe, in a way that everything between two specific values (e.g., `start` and `end`) is deleted, including the two values. These values can repeat, as in:

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | start |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | end |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | start |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 0 |
| 10 | end |
| 11 | 1 |

So the desired output would be:

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the answer from Tamil above, this is how I managed to implement it in my dataframe. It should be more efficient since it uses itertuples and not iterrows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8], 'c2': ['1', 'start', '3', 'end','5','start','end',0]})
df2 = copy.copy(df)
flag = False
list_a = []

for j in df.itertuples():
    if j.c2 == 'start':
        flag = True
        list_a.append((j))
    elif j.c2 =='end':
        flag = False
        list_a.append((j))
    elif flag:
        list_a.append((j))

list_a = tuple(list_a) 
to_remove_df = pd.DataFrame(list_a, columns=['index','c1','c2'])
to_remove_df = to_remove_df["c2"]
removed_df = pd.merge(df, to_remove_df, on=["c2"], how="outer", indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated a similar `dataframe` like yours. This is not an efficient way to do it, but it can work.

`df1`:

```
   c1     c2
0   1      1
1   2  start
2   3      3
3   4    end
4   5      5
5   6  start
6   7    end
7   8      0
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import copy

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8], 'c2': ['1', 'start', '3', 'end','5','start','end',0]})
df2 = copy.copy(df)
flag = False
for i, j in df.iterrows():
    if j['c2'] == 'start':
        flag = True
        df2 = df2.drop(df.index[[i]])
    elif j['c2'] =='end':
        flag = False
        df2 = df2.drop(df.index[[i]])
    elif flag:
        df2 = df2.drop(df.index[[i]])
```

output `df2`:

```
   c1 c2
0   1  1
4   5  5
7   8  0
```

Comment: This seems like a solution. However, I have to analyze >40 files with >2000000 rows each. Iterrows seems to be not the best to deal with such huge files (at least, this is why assumes that my script hasn't still reached the end of the process). Do you have any idea on how to make the process faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use masks

```
mask1 = df.c2.shift(-1) == "start"                                                    
mask2 = df.c2.shift(1) == "end"                                                       
newDf = (df.loc[mask1 | mask2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
   c1 c2
0   1  1
1   5  5
2   8  0
```

Comment: This would capture it only if the interval between"start" and "end" is costant, wouldn't it?

Comment: I tried with this dataframe : df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'c2': [1, 'start', 3, 'end',5,'start',3,5,7,'end',0]}) and it works perfectly !